# Is my question permitted (saved game editor)?

Tags: discussion, policy, ethics

I suppose I ought to have asked here, before asking [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46119/wizardry-8-saved-game-editor-trainer-cheat-engine).

Am I allowed to ask for a saved game editor / cheat engine? Or is that in some way disallowed for trying to circumvent DRM or similar?

If not valid, please ask me to delete it, as I have already found an answer and posted it.

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2618/246 and https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2607/246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't, and shouldn't attempt to, enforce civil agreements between third parties or laws of any country. It's impossible to do consistently and accurately - turns out there are lots of countries with different laws.

Your question looks fine to me.

Comment: However, I might note that this assuredly doesn't mean that Software Recommendations endorses breaking the law, if it is against the law. However, even if it is against the law in your country, it could still be useful for people in other countries.